# Polymorphic Associations in Rails for different 'author' models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

How would a Polymorphic Association (here: *Comments*) be itself associated with different types of Authors?

Starting from …

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => :true
end
```

… I'd need to have one author being from model *Hosts, ID 5* and another one from *Users, 2*.

How could path helpers look like…

```
<%= link_to comment.author.name, user_path(comment.author) %>
```

… when "user_path" or "host_path" are dynamic, depending on the author model?

**EDIT*****

There are Events, Places etc. that can have comments like so:

```
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

To the polymorphic Comment model i would like to add IDs and Types to refer to Authors of comments:

```
  create_table "comments", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "commentable_id"
    t.string   "commentable_type"
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
  end
```

An Events page displays comments, and clicking on an author name should take me either to User(5) oder AnotherModel(2), depending on who wrote the comment.

I'd like to know how everybody handles this kind of situation. Should I think about adding a second polymorphic "middle layer", such as "profile", that could hold the subclasses "User", "Host" and so forth?

**EDIT 2**

Having only one User model would make life easier here obviously, but that cannot be done for other reasons. And in general i'm interested how this could be organized well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply putting

```
<%= link_to comment.author.name, comment.author %>
```

should do the trick. If you want more flexibility, I would suggest

```
link_to ..., action_in_host_path(comment.author) if comment.author.kind_of? Host
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solution would require a `belongs_to :author`, i suppose? Only there is no author model. So using `belongs_to :author, :class => "User"` would enable it. But then again, i must not tie the comment to one particular author model (need hosts, users, …)

Comment: So may I understand that way: both Users and Hosts can create comments on Users and Hosts as author? Then your comment requires a polymorphic author, just like you did with the :commentable.

Comment: Thanks, needed to have that confirmed in my head :through => other users :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've used in the past (in a view helper), but it uses an eval:

```
def model_path(model, options = {})
    {:format => nil}.merge(options)
    format = (options[:format].nil? ? 'nil' : "'#{options[:format].to_s}'")
    eval("#{model.class.to_s.downcase}_path(#{model.id}, :format => #{format})")
end
```

Use like this:

```
<%= link_to comment.author.name, model_path(comment.author) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a possible solution, but please have a look at my other comment, since `comment.author.name` would require a dedicated `belongs_to`?

Comment: (I think blackbird's answer is better than mine, evals give me the heeby-jeebies...) If your comment has an author, then it must have a relationship (polymorphic in this case) with the author. If by "author" you meant "author of the commentable" then use `comment.commentable.author` in place of `comment.author`.

Answer (score 0):

Would [polymorphic_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) help?

> <%= link_to comment.author.name, polymorphic_url(comment.commentable)
>   %>